# keeping images aligned with text with flask

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to create a web app with flask. On each image I am adding descriptors underneath but for some images the descriptions are longer then others.

The image below is an example of my app running but as you can see the third image got shifted over and so the fourth image is now below that 
full view of what's going on: [image: ![enter image description here]

the pictures are the size I want but you can see how the longer text shifts the 3rd image, 
here is the html (warning I know very little html )

```
<!-- <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>

        {{image_names}}
        <hr>
        {% for image_name in image_names %}

            <img class="img-responsive" src=" {{url_for('send_image', filename=image_name)}}">
            <p>Hi</p>
    {% endfor %}

</body>
</html> -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <!-- <h1 class="page-header">Thumbnail Gallery</h1> -->
        </div>
        <!-- {{image_names}} -->
        <hr>

        {% for element in range(size) %}
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <img class="img-responsive" src=" {{url_for('send_image', filename=image_names[element])}}">
            <p> {{test[element]}}</p> 
          <!-- grabbing from a dictionary  <p> {{test2["bob"]}}</p> -->

        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you looping seems to be correct, this seems to be a class/bootstrap div nesting issue.

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: that the error is how you are building your layout. The way you are nesting your divs.